# SVG transform rotate just works in FF

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, svg-animate

I need to rotate a SVG with javascript , i can do it in Firefox with this code :

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('mySVG').setAttribute('transform','rotate(30,20,20)');">rotate It</button>
<svg id="mySVG" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="33"><path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"/></svg>
```

But this code won't work in other browsers like : CHROME , IE, SAFARI.
How can i fix that?

Comment: Use CSS instead …?

Comment: I need to rotate in DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an SVG 2 feature which is [not yet fully implemented by Chrome and Safari](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20transform). I think in SVG 1.1 the transform attribute is not valid for `<svg>`.
For now just apply the transform attribute to the `<path>` element, it works in Chrome and Safari as well:

```
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#mySVG path').setAttribute('transform','rotate(30,20,20)');"></button>
```

You may want to create a larger viewbox to fit the rotated path.